# The web API controller action name can not be determined by the type of the request

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

Doing a REST styled API I would like to know how I deal with duplicate action names:

```
public SchoolyearBrowseResponse Get(int userId)
{
    return _service.GetSchoolyears(userId);
}

public SchoolyearOpenResponse Get(int id)
{
    return _service.OpenSchoolyear(id);
}
```

It is said that the action`s name should be the request type. Now I have TWO Get methods with an int parameter which is not possible in C#.

Should I name the 2nd Get: `Open(int id)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Doing a REST styled API I would like to know how I deal with duplicate action names

In a RESTful styled API you should never have to deal with such duplicates. In a RESTful styled API you are dealing with resources.

So in your particular case you have 2 resources:

- a user
- a school year

So you would have the following routes:

- `/users/{userId}/schoolyears` -> which corresponds to your first action
- `/shoolyears/{id}` -> which corresponds to your second action

So:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    public SchoolyearBrowseResponse GetSchoolYears(int userId)
    {
        return _service.GetSchoolyears(userId);
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class SchoolYearsController : ApiController
{
    public SchoolyearOpenResponse Get(int id)
    {
        return _service.OpenSchoolyear(id);
    }
}
```

and the final step is your routes:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "UserSchoolYears",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{userId}/schoolyears",
        defaults: new { controller = "Users", action = "GetSchoolYears" }
    );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

As a side note I would like to mention that a school year for a user (your `SchoolyearBrowseResponse`) class hardly makes sense. Normally for a given user you have a list of school years. And if you wanted to get a specific school year for a user you would use `/users/{userId}/schoolyears/{schoolyearid}`.

Comment: "Normally for a given user you have a list of school years" But I have a List<BrowseSchoolyearDTO> inside my SchoolyearBrowseResponse class. Does that makes sense? Or I have not understood you...

Comment: Thanks again Darin, I like your answer and its really helpfull :)

Comment: Hm... one thing still comes to my mind. Why can I not put the GetSchoolyears back in the SchoolyearController when it has now a unique name?

Comment: Ok looking at the ressource path: /shoolyears/{id} is already taken so I can not make SchoolyearController.GetSchoolyears => /schoolyears/{userId} I would have to make it: /schoolyears/user/{id} now its unique. But is that good resource path design?

Answer (score 2):

a typical solution would be naming then in the following order :)

```
_service.OpenSchoolyearByYear(id);
_service.OpenSchoolyearByUserId(id);
```

Comment: I have a List<BrowseSchoolyearDTO> inside my SchoolyearBrowseResponse class. Your method names does not make sense to me.